# Why do some overlapping Area 51 sites get closed as dups and others stay open?

Tags: discussion, area-51, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, users

When users close a potential site on Area 51, it says "This proposal would tend to drain audience from another Stack Exchange site."  But, in many cases, we are not even talking about existing Stack Exchange sites, but merely ones that are proposed on Area 51.

I tried to start a "wikipedia" site suggestion, that would cover the online world of Wikipedia which is enormous, and I got shut down because a guy who was doing one for wiki-software only (not online wikipedia) rallied his buddies to shut my suggestion down.  And then he just added, "and wikipedia" to his proposal to justify it.

On the other hand look at Politics, it overlaps both US politics and World politics, yet they are all allowed to continue as non-dups.

What is the logic or reasoning going on to justify shutting down dup suggestions sites?

(none of which are actual active stack exchange sites)

Why are some dup suggestions allowed to fly and others fail?

Is it merely that one has more aggressive users than another?

Answer (score 2):

There's massive duplication on Area 51; the other day I counted something like 9 different music proposals that could all easily be merged.

I think that the only reasons why so many duplicates/overlapping proposals stay open is because (a) it's not that easy to notice or find duplicates, and (b) there aren't that many people who can close.

The team has stated that duplicate proposals *will* be dealt with before they reach beta, so most of the duplication you're noticing probably has a limited lifespan.